# ALC889 - GA-P55-UD4 -no sound - Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: sound

I have computer with a Gigabyte P55A-UD4 motherboard. I have on-board audio - Realtek ALC889. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and have no sound. please please heeeelp :). i have tryed to install high definition audio codecs from realtek but it doesn't work. in bios the azalia codec is turned on. ps : sorry for my english.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 12)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
03:00.1 IDE interface: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362/JMB363 Serial ATA Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 IDE interface: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Device 91a3 (rev 11)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
06:03.0 IDE interface: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. IT8213 IDE Controller
06:07.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

aplay -l

```
karta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], urządzenie 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 0: Intel [HDA Intel], urządzenie 1: ALC889 Digital [ALC889 Digital]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], urządzenie 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], urządzenie 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], urządzenie 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
karta 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], urządzenie 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
  Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

i will answer myself :) - i was using wrong output on the rear panel. it works under w7 but not under linux. sorry but i 'm using linux from 2 days . sorry for my english.